# Excepted type "scalar" but got "PeristentCollection" bug under Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

> The form's client data is expected to be of type scalar, but is an
>   instance of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection. You can avoid
>   this error by setting the "data_class" option to
>   "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" or by adding a client transformer
>   that transforms Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection to scalar.

Here's what I got when using a form using collections,

I've put the concerned files under Gist, i removed all unecessary code : https://gist.github.com/2769672

I'm working on a `TeamType` form, (class `Team`), I have 2 collections fields "`Conditions`" and "`Links`"

This problem happened just after i ran composer.phar update (I use Symfony 2.1).

What I don't understand is why i'm getting this although i have the "`data_class`" options

Thanks

Comment: 2.1 is not yet officially released - I'd expect it to be buggy.

Comment: y, but all PR are travis-ci tested, so there should not have major bug introduced in PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4374